# Pushing messages from server to client with Indy

Tags: indy, indy10

I have a general question about the server/client sequence for Indy 10.  In looking at examples, it seems that the client must first make a request and then the server responds in its Execute handler.  In my application, I want the server to asynchronously push out information when available and for the client(s) to accept that information without having made a request.  Is this control sequence possible?

Comment: The request/response model is how MOST servers are designed to work. That is not unique to Indy. But yes, what you are asking for is possible in Indy, though it does take some work to setup. On the client side, simply run a timer/thread that continuously reads from the connection. On the server side, it is generally best to give each client a thread-safe queue of data and have `OnExecute` check and send that queue, and then you can push data into a client's queue when needed. I've posted examples of exactly this many times in many forums, including on StackOverflow.

Comment: Though, this is not the only way to handle things. It really depends on your particular requirements, protocol design, coding style, etc.

Comment: As I understand your answer you are saying that the client(s) should periodically poll the server. Put another way, the server cannot speak to the client until the client initiates a request/response sequence.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Re-read what I said more carefully: "*On the client side, simply run a timer/thread that **continuously reads** from the connection*". The client can just read from its connection without having to send a request to the server first. When the server has something to send, it can just send it.